# I wrote a code in C that send a pointer to function to print it, but there is a time running error

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, pointers, char

this is the code:
the code needs to send the array to the function and the function will print but it seems there is run time error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printArray(char* p, int len)
{
    for (p; p < p + len; p++)
    {
        printf("%c", *p);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    char* msg = "hi jyegq meet me at 2 :)"; 
    printArray(msg, strlen(msg));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you change `p`, `p + len` also changes. `p` will never catch up to `p+ len`.

Comment: when du you think `p < p + len` will become false? Whatever the current value of the pointer is, you always comapre it to the same pointer `+ len`; it's the same as if you wrote `for( int i=0; i<i+1: i++ )`

Comment: Using the termination chractaer for strings, you don't really need the length: `for (; *p != '\0'; p++) { ... }`. NB: (except for strings usually) it's a good idea to pass the length to functions that work on an array.

Comment: Conversely, `for (const char *stop = p+len; p != stop; ++p)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (p; p < p + len; p++)
```

This condition is all the time *true*, as you do not modify `len` and `p` is identical with `p`, even after mutatations.  You need to define a new pointer `q` that is initially equal to `p` and mutate only `q`.

```
void printArray(char* p, int len)
{
    for (char *q = p; q < p + len; q++)
        printf("%c", *q);
    printf("\n");
}
```

It is better to define `char const* p`, as there is no reason to mutate `p`.

Answer (score 2):

In this for loop

```
for (p; p < p + len; p++)
```

the condition is always evaluates to logical `true` (except the case when `len` is equal to `0` or has a negative value that invokes undefined behavior) because `p` is evidently less than `p + len`.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
void printArray( const char *s, size_t len )
{
    for ( const char *p = s; p < s + len; p++)
    {
        putchar( *p );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Pay attention to that the pointer parameter should have the qualifier `const` because the pointed string is not changed within the function and the second parameter should have the type `size_t`. It is the return type of the function `strlen`.